# Как выбрать нужную кнопку

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Существую цикл из определенного количества аннотаций, при каждой аннотации добавляется кнопка на вью, как после добавления всех кнопок в коде выбрать нужную?

Пример

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    UIButton * testView2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, hightArray1 + 90 + 37 * i, 280, 35)];
    testView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    testView2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    testView2 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionTestView1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:testView2]; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что использовать viewWithTag в этом случае не очень хорошо. В этом случае вы фактически используете view для хранения model, что неправильно в рамках MVC паттерна. Лучше было бы создать массив и в него сложить все UIButtons, и потом их получать по индексу:

```
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton*)buttonArray[index];
```

Comment: Я создал наследника класса UIButton со своим числовым свойством, но ваш метод тоже работает, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Добавте для кнопки tag. `testView2.tag = 100;` Далее можете достать кнопку по тэгу: `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];`

Comment: Огромное спасибо